# Can phishing site URL shorten into numbers?

Tags: phishing, url

[image]

A suspected hacker was trying to get the user to input those numbers (2412958) in their address book. And user knows that the numbers are weird.

Can URLs be shortened in texts like that?

Comment: By definition, that's not a URL. It *might* be a link to something, though. If these are just numbers, then no.

Comment: If these numbers are real phishing URL, how can hacker make it?

Comment: you mean, like this: [2412958](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/216035/can-phishing-site-url-shorten-into-numbers)  or [2412958](http://google.com)?

Comment: As I say, it is not a URL, by definition. It might direct a phone to go somewhere bad, but I can't tell by just the numbers. And the redirection is not a URL.

Comment: Technically, 2412598 could be an IP address expressed as an integer, but it appears to come out as 0.36.209.158, which would be a nonsense address. More likely the attack involves calling or sending a message to that phone number.

Comment: It would be useful to provide a transcript and rough translation of the other text in the screenshot for those of us who don't speak the language shown (Korean?)

Comment: right. It's Korean

Comment: Depending on the application and type of phone, the "linkification" could be being done locally. On my Android phone, in both text messages and emails, things that look like they might be a phone-number (including short-form SMS numbers, like the above) or that look vaguely like dates are often turned into a link that takes you to the dialer/message-compose-screen/calendar as appropriate.

Comment: No. The phone SMS app will not treat it as a URL since "http|https" scheme is missing

Comment: @mootmoot I didn't say it treats it as a URL, but that it automatically turns (some) numbers into clickable "things". I just sent myself the (completely plain) text "This is a number 2412958. Is it clickable?" and on receipt, the `2412958` is blue and underlined, exactly as in the OP's image. Clicking on it takes me to the phone's dialer, with the number pre-filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is a SMS [Short code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code).

Although IP address can be converted to decimal, the phone SMS application will not see it as an URL because "http" prefix is missing.

A smartphone SMS message box application usually does the following data highlights and link (parsing) for user conveniences.

- URL with a http prefix. Let you click and open it from a browser
- Phone number. Let you click and dial the number
- Any number that looks like SMS [short or long code](https://www.simplycast.com/interactive-marketing-support/faqs/shortcode-vs-longcode/#contact). Let you click and open SMS compose box and use the code as the recipient.

Since every country SMS short code and long code length are vary, it is easier for developer simply parse a 5~8 digits number as short code. Although this is a bad idea when many services start sending [Multi-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) number to SMS.

A rogue SMS scammer can bait the user by asking them to reply to the short code with a blank response. When the gullible user response to it, the message will subscribe the user phone with a useless push message, which will charge the user $2~$10 from time to time (weekly/fortnight/month).  Such fraud/abuse is done using a method called [Reverse SMS billing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_SMS_billing).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. It's called IPv4 to IP Decimal [Conversion](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/ip), but your messenger thinks of it as phone number (I checked on WhatsApp and Android Messenger) and so will give you a choice to either open it via apps that call/message (true caller and such). Also [2412958](https://2412958) might not work.

Comment: thanks! It will be helpful to twitter Korean users for preventing hacking

Comment: Yes it is possible, but that's not what this is - it's not a URL and a phone is not going to interpret the numbers as an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes phishing links can be converted to numbers or any text with random characters.

But in your case the decimal number is not a phishing link. The number **`2412958`** when converted , translates to **`IP 0.36.209.158`**. This IP is part of **`IANA Special Use reserved IP address pool`** ,  i.e, this IP pool is maintained by **`IANA`** and will not be used to host phishing sites.

But there is still a chance that the decimal may have *`embedded hyperlink`* in it and when clicked on it , may open or redirect to a phishing link. You may see if it redirects to hyperlink, by hovering your mouse over it. The link will be present on the bottom left of your browser.

References:

- http://whois.domaintools.com/0.36.209.158
- https://www.browserling.com/tools/ip-to-dec